# Colaboratory install Tensorflow Object Detection Api

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, google-colaboratory

I succesfully executed in Google Colaboratory a notebook of training model and image recognition in Tensorflow.
Now I want to start a new notebook with [Object Detection Api](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). When I execute my code I get following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'
```

How can I install Object Detection Api in Colaboratory? I follow the install [instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md) but I can't execute:

```
# From tensorflow/models/research/
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example notebook that shows the installation and configuration of the TensorFlow object detection API:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kHEQK2uk35xXZ_bzMUgLkoysJIWwznYr

The departure from the install instructions on the site include modifying `sys.path` directly and executing `model_builder_test.py` using `%run`. The reason for these differences is that when running in Colab, you're already in a Python interpreter, so you don't need to worry about modifying the environment for a future shell invocation of `python`.

Comment: Thanks Bob, following Tensorflow documentation, we should add to PYTHONPATH even "tensorflow/models/research/", so I would add to cell 23: sys.path.append('/content/models/research')

Answer (score 4):

You just forgot to *Add path* the **slim** folder

If you run **locally** https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
```

On the **Colab**:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/base_folder/slim')
```

Notes: The Google Colaboratory also required to install some necessary packages firstly:

```
!apt-get install -y -qq protobuf-compiler python-pil python-lxml
```

My example: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EFtTACXnWUoaGGAVqCwYS_JS-6Jr6upg#scrollTo=Z2GjW06y_6gO

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
!pip install tensorflow-object-detection-api
```

Comment: this is the one that succeeds, if you follow this tensorflow tutorial--https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/tf2_object_detection . Before importing the object detection tools, run the above code. The errors disappeared for my case

Answer (score 0):

Runs:

- step 1:

```js
import os
    import pathlib
    
    # Clone the tensorflow models repository if it doesn't already exist
    if "models" in pathlib.Path.cwd().parts:
      while "models" in pathlib.Path.cwd().parts:
        os.chdir('..')
    elif not pathlib.Path('models').exists():
      !git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/tensorflow/models
```

- Step 2:

```js
# Install the Object Detection API
%%bash
cd models/research/
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
python -m pip install .
```