# Why do I get "No module named Object detection" in Google colab?

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I am trying to do  object detection using tensor flow in google colab but everytime I run the following code

```
%run model_builder_test.py
```

I get this error

```
     ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
        /content/drive2/My Drive/object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py in <module>()
        21 
        22 from google.protobuf import text_format
   ---> 23 from object_detection.builders import model_builder
        24 from object_detection.meta_architectures import faster_rcnn_meta_arch
        25 from object_detection.meta_architectures import rfcn_meta_arch

            ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'
```

I have setup the python path as they said but still keep getting this error.I will give you link to my program below
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1iko-bEUfxLimtbGqCmrypRyEzaWzE3vu?usp=sharing
Please help

Comment: Please share your linked notebook publicly. Presently, access is restricted, so folks reading this question can't see the notebook.

Comment: O sorry,here I ve done it the link is now shareable

Comment: @PragyanSubedi Look at this solution here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48663207/colaboratory-install-tensorflow-object-detection-api)

Comment: @JimitVaghela already looked up, I have given the path but still does not work

Comment: Is it the same error still?

Answer (score 0):

%set_env PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/content/models/research:/content/models/research/slim:/content/models

Answer (score -1):

```py
import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += ':/kaggle/working/models/research/:/kaggle/working/models/research/slim/'
```